# Is it possible to get a GWT web page as html page?

Tags: java, html, jquery-ui, gwt

I have a GWT web page designed in my web application, now we are removing the gwt and adding jquery.
Is there any simple process to convert GWT page into HTML page just UI designing?

If so please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the GWT client java is converted to a HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221205/how-does-the-gwt-client-java-is-converted-to-a-html)

Comment: @KiranRS it is internal process which is given in that. I want to know  how can i do it?

Comment: If you want to change to a JQuery client then you have to, er, write a JQuery client.  You could pinch the generated HTML from your GWT client but it'd be horrible and you're better off doing it from scratch imo.